# Jasmine/Angular: TypeError: Cannot read property '$modules/$injector' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery, angular-mock

I am trying to run jasmine test cases and i am landing on '$modules' of undefined. I am loading unminified and latest versions of libraries as below,

```
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="lib/boot.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-1.3.9.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-mocks-1.0.1.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here-->
<script src="src/test.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here-->
<script src="specs/testSpec.js"></script>
```

My Spec code snippet is below,

```
describe('TestController', function () {
    var $httpBackend, $rootScope;
    beforeEach(function () { angular.module('test'); });
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector, $http, $window) {
       // Set up the mock http service responses
       $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    }));
});
```

I get the following errors,
**TypeError: Cannot read property '$modules' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot set property '$injector' of undefined**

Any information would help. thanks !

Comment: Hi. Can you provide a little more of your code, to see that the loading of framework stuff is correct? It seems unusual that you're loading the tests with a <script> tag, it's usually in the karma.conf.js file. Is there more code in the test spec other than what you pasted here?

Comment: @syonip Hi, Thanks for your reply. I figured the issue. It was the version mismatch between angular and angular-mocks. Updated the angular-mocks version and the error disappeared.

Comment: @syonip: And, i am not actually using karma, yet. I am just using plain simple jasmine for now.

Comment: cool. you had a karma tag in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the version mismatch between angular.js and angular-mock.js.

Updated the version of angular-mock.js to 1.3.9(same as angular.js) and issue was gone.

Comment: angular mocks 1.3.9 not found, are you sure that's works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the line where you define what module you are going to run your tests at:

```
beforeEach(module('AngularModuleName'));
```